# prepareForValidation does not work Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to make a whitelist of `id` that can be created, but for some reason it doesn't work

```
    protected function prepareForValidation(){
        $WhiteListes = WhiteList::all();

        foreach ($WhiteListes as $WhiteList){
            if ($WhiteList->server_id == $this->id) {
                $this->merge(['id' => $this->id]);
            } else {
                $this->merge(['id' => null]);
            }
        }

    }
```

This returns `null`. Although it should return an `$this->id`

I've already tried doing this

```
        foreach ($WhiteListes as $WhiteList){
            $test = $WhiteList->server_id == $this->id;
            dd($test); 
        }
```

This returns `True` to me
Why does it work so crookedly? And how do I do it right

Comment: you are not "returning" anything from there ... unless the last record you got was the one matching the 'id' then you are always going to be merging in `'id' => null`, because its a loop ... perhaps you want to break the loop after finding the match?

Comment: @lagbox if the function returns a bool value, if the expression takes the value ```True```, then the loop stops and passes ```$this->id```, but the loop does not stop and passes ```null```

Comment: Also, the entire `foreach()` is pointless; just query for it: `$this->merge(['id' => WhiteList::where('server_id', $this->id)->first()->server_id ?? null])`

Comment: No problem! If you ever find yourself loading _every record_ (vial `::all()` or `->get()` without `where()` clauses), just to loop them and find a single one, rethink your approach. That kind of code is inefficient and redundant when you can trivially return a single record from the database based on conditions. Cheers! 

Comment: `...where(...)->value('server_id')`, btw